# Win32 c++ console application and Eclipse

Tags: c++, windows, eclipse

I wish to build a project from a really old version of Visual Studio in Eclipse instead. The win32 console app includes windows.h.

The question is, what libraries do I need to satisfy the windows dependencies? The app reads and writes to serial ports. Any tips for setting up my project to build correctly?

Thanks,

Barry

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Windows_SDK

Answer (score 2):

All windows libs are in Platform SDK. By the way there must be library directories set in Visual Studio options. Also inspect your VS project's properties, library dependencies might be there I guess

Comment: @Baz, please, follow the link @clamp gave in his comment to your question

Comment: Am I right in saying that I will need to use the Microsoft Compiler Toolchain to link against the libraries I use from the SDK? http://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsdg_html_chunked/ChToolsMSChain.html

Comment: To link against libraries you only need to say your linker which libraries to use. You can declare libraries names and paths in your toolchain options (in project properties window). I think you can choose toolchain you like.